# Ehcache stores but not retrieves (Ehcache + Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, ehcache

I'm using ehcache to cache entities using hibernate.

Looking at ehcache monitor, everything seems to work fine (flush put cache count to zero, and reload put count back in one), but if i change some value directly on the db and reload, the updated value is showed and not the cached one. I dont know if this is the expected behaviour, but it will be strange as a cache to act like that.

I've tried every solution found to figure this out with no success.

Comment: For a cache surely you do want to see the value that is the one in the db - the cache is meant to be a copy of the db.

Comment: Indeed it is, but if change a value before the cache expires, it must return the cached value, right? Unless the cache can be smart enough to detect the value change on the db

Comment: Which is the correct value the db or the cacjh - if the cache why is itt not in the db?

Comment: Suppose the following steps:
1. DB has value 'a'
2. Hit the page so the cache stores value 'a'
3. Update DB with value 'b' (before cache expires)
4. Refresh page and get value 'b'

I dont know if the cache was updated too, or if jpa is reading directly from the db thus bypassing the cache.

Comment: @Mark, I think what Jams is asking refers to JPA always fetching data from database and not from cache, even before the cache expires.

Comment: @Jame you say reload - what exactly do you mean by this.

Comment: Found solution on this other [question][1]

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563685/jpa-hibernate-ehcache-unexpected-behavior

Comment: I faced the same problem and got the solution right here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11563685/jpa-hibernate-ehcache-unexpected-behavior

Comment: you should check this [inefficient-hibernate-ehcache-performance-issue-fixed][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334492/inefficient-hibernate-ehcache-performance-issue-fixed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the expected behaviour. The database is the source of all correct data the cache is just there to speed up access to the data in the database. If the data differs then the cache is wrong by definition.

**So if you reload the cache is reloaded from the database.**

If you save data through Hibernate then the data is written to the cache and the database. There can be an issue here when you have more than one thread/process reading or writing. For how to manage this see [caching strategies in the Hibernate documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html/ch06.html#caching-strategies-list)

In general updating the database directly causes issue the cache will not have the correct data unless it is notified that it must invalidate the data it has and/or reload from the database.

Comment: Actually i'm updating the data directly on the database in order to test hibernate to get the cached data instead of the stored on the database

Comment: @Jame you are not that clear - as the aim is always to get the same data as in the database - are you trying to test a particular error?

Comment: i'm trying to test if the cache its properly working. I know that the the idea behind caching is to speed up access time, but if i alter the source of caching directly (in this case the database), the returned value must be the cached one, not the altered value on the source, otherwise the cache will perform just as read directly to the source

Comment: @Jams - sorry I am confused - the cache should ideally always have the data that the database has - and the database is always correct - the values do not match then the cache has a bug not the database