# JPA + Hibernate + EHCache, unexpected behavior

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, ehcache

I'm trying to implement EHCache into my working prototype, where I have a *javax.persistence.Entity* representing a table on my database (MySQL, mysql-connector-java-5.1.20.jar), which be provided as XML to the consumers.

The issue I'm facing is that seems Hibernate still retrieving the data from the database, **even when EHCache stores the query result on memory**.

I'm using the [EHCache monitor](http://ehcache.org/documentation/operations/monitor#api) to see the count of items in memory, and changing the data directly on database before the cache expires to know if the cached data is actually used.

I been looking for a replication for this issue without succeed, so maybe I'm missing something (I just geting into the java world).

### My files

**pom.xml**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
    <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.4.Final</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.terracotta</groupId>
    <artifactId>ehcache-probe</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.2</version>
</dependency>
```

**Entity class**

```
package myPrototype.entities

import javax.persistence.Cacheable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.NamedQueries;
import javax.persistence.NamedQuery;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Entity @Cacheable
@Cache(usage=CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY)
@Table(name = "Cars")
@XmlRootElement
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Cars d"),
    [...]
public class Cars implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Basic(optional = false)
        @NotNull
        @Column(name = "id")
    @ReferenceField
    private int id;
    [...]
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache>
  <cache name="myPrototype.entities.Cars"
    maxElementsInMemory="500"
    eternal="false"
    overflowToDisk="false"
    timeToIdleSeconds="60"
    timeToLiveSeconds="120" />
</ehcache>
```

* *I tried setting eternal="true", but the result still the same*

**persistence.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="MyPrototype" transaction-type="JTA">
    <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
    <jta-data-source>java:app/jdbc/mysqlserver/prototype</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <shared-cache-mode>ENABLE_SELECTIVE</shared-cache-mode>
    <properties>
      <!-- property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory"/ -->
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class" value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory" />
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
      <property name="hibernate.cache.region_prefix" value=""/>
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

* *I tried switching between SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory and EhCacheRegionFactory*

**EJB**

```
import myPrototype.entities.Cars
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ejb.Stateless;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.PersistenceContext;

@Stateless
public class CarsEJB {

    @PersistenceContext(unitName="MyPrototype")
    private EntityManager em;

    @Override
    public List<Cars> getCars() {
        return (List<Cars>)em.createNamedQuery("Cars.findAll").setMaxResults(200).getResultList();
    }

}
```

* *Added to clarify how I run the query*

Like I said, I can see a count of items in memory through EHCache monitor, so I noted the following:
- The ehcache configuration is property loaded elements are expiring
- The elements expiration not being reseted when the query runs while they still alive (they expired N seconds after the first query).

Again; I'm quite a newbie with java, so asume I could be missing basic concepts.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: What code are you executing, what do you expect it to do, and what does it do instead?

Comment: @JBNizet For instance; When I ran my query more than once (trough a working Restful service) and getting the objects, it's aways retrieves the data from the database ignoring the cached objects on the first time.

Comment: i think you should also investigate by setting property in persistance.xml <property name="hibernate.generate_statistics" value="true"/> and check hibernate statistics, this will help you to check why query is not hitting cache

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hibernate will never execute queries on your cache. What it can do is execute a query on the database, cache the results, and return these cached results the next time you execute the same query, with the same parameters. But to do that, the query, each time it's executed, must be cacheable.

WIth the JPA API, this is done using query hints, directly on the named query definition, or each time you create a query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Cars.findAll", 
            query = "SELECT d FROM Cars d",
            hints = {@QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true")})
```

Now that the query is cacheable, Hibernate will load the IDs of the cars from the database the first time this query is executed, and from the query cache afterwards. Then the corresponding cars themselves will be loaded from the entity cache.

Comment: Great! that's exactly what I wanted and it works! Thanks so much!. Now, is there a way to set the hint to all the queries by default?

Comment: You really don't want that. Many queries will query data that frequently changes, and the cache would constantly be invalidated. Moreover, every entity returned by a query must be in the second-level cache, else you have a big N + 1 problem. And of course, you have queries which must not be cached, because they depend on the current time, or take parameters that constantly change. Databases are fast. Optimize only if necessary.

Comment: Fair enough! I was thinking on explicitly disable the hint, but you're right, besides it's more readable having the hint right there.  Thanks again!