# Caching for the frontend application

Tags: angularjs, spring, hibernate, caching

I am working on a web application that uses Spring MVC framework and hibernate for the backend and using DAO classes and DTOs for persistence. After entity fetch the dto is being sent as a JSON to the frontend that uses angularJS for the front end.

I am asked to add caching to the frontend application.The dB call is to be avoided if the the request is hit again within some time frame. Please suggest me how i can implement this. Also please tell me some different ways how caching can be implemented to make frontend perform better.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should use EhCache here some tutorials

http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-caching-and-ehcache-example/

or

https://amitstechblog.wordpress.com/2011/11/08/configuring-ehcache-with-jpa-hibernate-spring/

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Presently the application is using EhCache, but presently facing some issue with this. Majorly the issue is when we have dto with parent child relationship, the id based fetch becomes problem and we get different values from the desired one. Is there any way if this can be improved.

Comment: i can't understand your issue, may be you are talking about this issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334492/inefficient-ehcache-performance