# Spring data JPA with Hibernate and Ehcache not working

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, ehcache, querydsl

I'm working on an application using Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and I'm trying to enable second level cache using ehcache. I broke up my application into two projects:

- CoreDataFacade: where I define data access operations using QueryDSL, Spring Data JPA with Hibernate and ehcache.
- QueryComponent: is a spring boot project that uses CoreDataFacade project to access data.

CoreDataFacade's configuration is as follows:

**pom.xml**

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.3.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.ehcache</groupId>
        <artifactId>ehcache-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.7</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-ehcache</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>  
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.33</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
        <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
        <version>0.9.1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-apt</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.mysema.querydsl</groupId>
        <artifactId>querydsl-jpa</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

**application-context.xml**

```
<jpa:repositories
    base-package="com.coredata.services.impl.sql.mysql.repositories" />

<bean id="dataSource" class="com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:driverClass="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:jdbcUrl="jdbc:mysql://localhost/FOO" p:user="****" p:password="****"
    p:acquireIncrement="5" p:minPoolSize="10" p:maxPoolSize="100"
    p:maxIdleTime="1200" p:unreturnedConnectionTimeout="120" />

<bean id="jpaVendorAdapter"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"
    p:database="MYSQL" p:showSql="true" p:generateDdl="true" />


<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean"
    p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" p:jpaVendorAdapter-ref="jpaVendorAdapter"
    p:packagesToScan="com.coredata.services.impl.sql.mysql.model">
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.provider_class">org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class">org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory
            </prop>
            <prop key="javax.persistence.sharedCache.mode">ENABLE_SELECTIVE</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.generate_statistics">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" />
```

**Entity Cache annotations**

```
@Entity
@Cacheable
@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, region="cache_states")
@Table(name="states")
public class State implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id_state")
    private int idState;
    ...
```

**ehcache.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">

    <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="10000" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120" timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        overflowToDisk="false" diskPersistent="false" />

    <cache name="cache_states" maxElementsInMemory="300" eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="5000" timeToLiveSeconds="5000" overflowToDisk="false">
    </cache>
</ehcache>
```

QueryComponent's configuration imports above configuration and exclude JPA:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("classpath:/component.properties")
@ImportResource({ "classpath:/application-context.xml"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration(exclude = { JpaRepositoriesAutoConfiguration.class })
public class Application {

    public void run(String... args) {   }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

When ComponentQuery starts everything is OK. When I execute a query to find all states in database, hibernate statistics are as follows:

```
Hibernate: select count(state0_.id_state) as col_0_0_ from states state0_
Hibernate: select state0_.id_state as id_stat1_5_, state0_.name_state as  name_e2_5_ from states state0_ limit ?
[2015-08-31 18:52:21.402] boot - 1946  INFO [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]    --- StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener:    Session Metrics {
    32992 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    238285 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    935976 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    269717 nanoseconds spent performing 4 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    68790 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
  }
```

When I repeat the same query I got this statistics:

```
Hibernate: select count(state0_.id_state) as col_0_0_ from states state0_
Hibernate: select state0_.id_state as id_stat1_5_, state0_.name_state as  name_e2_5_ from states state0_ limit ?
[2015-08-31 19:26:48.479] boot - 1946  INFO [SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor-1]    --- StatisticalLoggingSessionEventListener:     Session Metrics {
    314930 nanoseconds spent acquiring 1 JDBC connections;
    0 nanoseconds spent releasing 0 JDBC connections;
    356832 nanoseconds spent preparing 2 JDBC statements;
    681615 nanoseconds spent executing 2 JDBC statements;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 JDBC batches;
    209324 nanoseconds spent performing 4 L2C puts;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
    0 nanoseconds spent executing 0 flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections);
    12368 nanoseconds spent executing 2 partial-flushes (flushing a total of 0 entities and 0 collections)
}
```

It seems that every query is putting results (4 states in database) in cache:

```
    269717 nanoseconds spent performing 4 L2C puts;
    209324 nanoseconds spent performing 4 L2C puts;
```

I expect second query to retrive data from cache but it statistics hits and misses are zero:

```
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C hits;
    0 nanoseconds spent performing 0 L2C misses;
```

My question is: why L2C hits and L2C misses are zero when I execute second query?

**UPDATE**

This is how I'm running my query

**Reposiory**

I'm working with QueryDSL with spring data jpa. I followed this [tutorial](http://www.javabeat.net/spring-data-jpa-querydsl-integration/) to integrate my JpaRepository using [QueryDslPredicateExecutor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/commons/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/querydsl/QueryDslPredicateExecutor.html)

```
public interface StateRepository extends JpaRepository<State, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<State> {
 }
```

**Service**

In my service I execute my query using queryDLS predicates and PathBuilder as shown in this great [article](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-search-language-spring-data-querydsl) so that, I can find States or any other entity by any field. E.g "StateName=Texas", "StatePopulation=26448193".

```
@Autowired
StateRepository repo;

public List<State> getStatesByFields(String options, Integer page, Integer pageSize,String order) {
    PredicateBuilder predicateBuilder = new PredicateBuilder().onEntity("State")
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(OPERATION_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(options + ",");
    while (matcher.find()) {
        predicateBuilder.with(matcher.group(1), matcher.group(2), matcher.group(3));
    }
    PageRequest pag = new PageRequest(page, page_size)
    BooleanExpression predicate = predicateBuilder.build();
    //findAll is provided by QueryDslPredicateExecutor interface
    Page<State> result = repo.findAll(predicate, pag);
}
```

Queries runs like charm, but data seems not be cached.

Comment: Add the queries you are running.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Inefficient EhCache Performance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27334492/inefficient-ehcache-performance)

Comment: @manish, I updated my question with information about queries.

Comment: @NassimMOUALEK, I think this question is not related with EhCache performace, is about cache storing. EhCache seems not being working.

Comment: Why are you bypassing Spring Boot and configure everything yourself? Have you used the correct `@Cacheable` annotation?

Comment: Also your cache is readonly, however your transaction isn't. What happens if you make the cache read/write or your query readonly.

Answer (score 8):

Entity cache only works if the entity is retrieved using its id e.g. load(), get(). It doesn't work if you use query.

To enable caching the query you have to use Query cache. e.g.

```
List blogs = sess.createQuery("from Blog blog where blog.blogger = :blogger")
    .setEntity("blogger", blogger)
    .setMaxResults(15)
    .setCacheable(true)
    .setCacheRegion("frontpages")
    .list();
```

or using jpa

```
query.setHint(“org.hibernate.cacheable”, true);
```

I'm not sure how to implement this with `QueryDslPredicateExecutor`, but hopes this will help to understand hibernate 2nd lvl cache

L2C hits and L2C misses are equal to zero means that hibernate never search the data from the cache because you are retrieving records using query without enabling the query cache

L2C puts not zero because hibernate cache the records to be used later if you retrieve the entity by its id(this is different than caching the query result)

Comment: Well not exactly. It will try to find a hit in the second level cache upon creating the result. A nice explanation [here](http://www.javalobby.org/java/forums/t48846.html) although a bit dated still applies.

Comment: @MangEngkus, thank you for your time and the explanation. Unfortunately, because of the project's deadline we decided not to implement the ehcache BUT we'll do it in the future. I tried to use query.setHint(“org.hibernate.cacheable”, true) in a demo project and It works, so we need to readapt our code to use it. I'll keep the question open anyway. If anyone have the same problem and find a way to use ehcache with QueryDslPredicateExecutor and find a solution.

Comment: @CharlieG Did you try using: **org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider** and **org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory** for *hibernate.cache.provider_class* and *hibernate.cache.region.factory_class*  respectively ?  We are able to get the cache working with Spring JPA and QueryDSL being used in our project. I shall be able to post an answer sometime soon.

Answer (score 2):

Your cache region configuration has a typo. In the entity class, your configuration (@Cache(usage = CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY, **region="cache_states"**)) points to a different region than one defined in ehcache.xml (cache **name="cache_estados"**)

Comment: Hi @R4J, my cache region configuration was a mistake when I was editing my question. Actually my ehcache.xml  region has the same name that I have in my entity configuration ("cache_states"). I updated my question. BTW I don't know why a downvote, but thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
@CacheConfig(cacheNames = "com.abc.domain.State")
public interface StateRepository extends CrudRepository<State, Integer>, QueryDslPredicateExecutor<State> {

    @QueryHints(value = {
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheable", value = "true"),
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheMode", value = "NORMAL"),
            @QueryHint(name = "org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value = "CacheRegion")
    })
    Page<State> findAll(Predicate predicate, Pageable pageable);

}
```

It worked for me.

Comment: This works for me. I only used ```org.hibernate.cacheable```

Comment: There are constants that can be used in place of org.hibernate.cacheable,cacheMode,cacheRegion they are in: import static org.hibernate.annotations.QueryHints.CACHEABLE,CACHE_MODE,CACHE_REGION

Answer (score 0):

This is what is done in our case. In fact, Spring JPA and QueryDSL were used. On an other note, QueryDSL is not preventing nor has anything to do with caching. Hope this answer helps.

Following are the code config you would need to work it out.

**Entity manager config bean**

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(
    basePackages = { "com.abc.examples.persistence.repository" },
    entityManagerFactoryRef = "entityManagerFactory",
    transactionManagerRef = "transactionManager"
)
@ComponentScan("com.abc.examples.persistence")
public class PersistenceConfig {

    /*Code omitted. Beans configured for other items like testDataSource, transactionManager*/

    @Bean(name = "entityManagerFactory")
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean localContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(
        @Qualifier("testDataSource") DataSource dataSource,
        @Value("${hibernate.show_sql}") String hibernateShowSql,
        @Value("${hibernate.generate_statistics}") String hibernateShowStats
        ) {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean factoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        factoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);
        factoryBean.setPackagesToScan("com.abc.examples.persistence.entity");
        factoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter());
        factoryBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);

        Properties hibernateProperties = new Properties();
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
        hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");

        factoryBean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties);
        return factoryBean;
    }
}
```

**Important things** to look for in the above config are

```
factoryBean.setSharedCacheMode(SharedCacheMode.ENABLE_SELECTIVE);
...
...
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.SingletonEhCacheProvider");
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.region.factory_class", "org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.SingletonEhCacheRegionFactory");
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache", "true");
hibernateProperties.setProperty("hibernate.cache.use_query_cache", "true");
```

**Cache Manager config bean (we used EhCache)**

```
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class CacheConfig {

    @Bean(name = "cacheManager")
    public EhCacheCacheManager ehCacheCacheManager() {
        return new EhCacheCacheManager(ehCache());
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager ehCache() {
        CacheManager cacheManager = CacheManager.create();

        Cache sampleEntityCache = new Cache(
            new CacheConfiguration("com.abc.examples.entity.SampleEntity", 500)
                    .memoryStoreEvictionPolicy(MemoryStoreEvictionPolicy.LRU)
                    .eternal(false)
                    .timeToLiveSeconds(60 * 60 * 24)
                    .timeToIdleSeconds(60 * 60 * 24)
                    .persistence(new PersistenceConfiguration().strategy(PersistenceConfiguration.Strategy.NONE))
        );
        cacheManager.addCache(sampleEntityCache);

        return cacheManager;
    }
}
```

**Entity class**

```
import org.hibernate.annotations.Cache;
import org.hibernate.annotations.CacheConcurrencyStrategy;

@Cache(usage= CacheConcurrencyStrategy.READ_ONLY,
    region="com.abc.examples.entity.SampleEntity") //This name should match with the name used in the CacheConfiguration above.
public class SampleEntity{
    @Id
    ...
    ...
    ..
}
```

Comment: Where is CacheConfiguration class implementation?